# How many capacity store data in apps iPad?

Tags: capacity

I'd like store files into application iPad and i'd like some information about how many capacity store data in own apps iPad. Please help me, thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about actual limitations but I've allowed the ability to record your own voice within the app. This can get sizeable. Just look up the various caching and storage options available for iOS.